# EJB Managed bean parent with argument in constructor

Tags: java, java-ee-8

Lets say I have a class hierarchy of `Human` and `Student` classes like this:

```
public abstract class Human{

    private final String type;

    public Human(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

@Stateless
public class Student extends Human {

    public Student() {
        super("STUDENT");
    }
}
```

I only need a managed bean of class `Student`. But on class `Human`, I get an error saying:

> Managed Bean must have a constructor with no parameters, or a
> constructor annotated @Inject

Is there a way to tell Java that I don't want a managed bean of type `Human`, and therefore I don't need a parameterless constructor?

Comment: I suspect that the fact that `Student` extends `Human` means that `Human` has to support the managed bean expectations.  Have you tried adding the Inject annotation to the parameterized constructor of `Human`?